# How can I automatically require gems for all files in a specific folder?

Tags: ruby

I would like to automatically require gems in 3 different files in a folder, instead of manually typing require 'gem_name' in every file. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: make a single file which requires the gems, then from that file require the other ruby files.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that illustrates one way you might do that.

File `gems.rb` contains one line requiring the Awesome Print gem:

```
require 'ap'
```

A second file contains:

```
require_relative 'gems.rb'

class T
  def t
   ap [1,2,[3,[4,5]]]
  end
end

T.new.t
[
    [0] 1,
    [1] 2,
    [2] [
        [0] 3,
        [1] [
            [0] 4,
            [1] 5
        ]
    ]
]
```

Require all your gems in `gems.rb` and begin files using those gems with `require` or a `require_relative`.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [Bundler](http://bundler.io).

1. Install Bundler: `gem install bundler`
2. Create Gemfile for your project (in Project_Root\Gemfile):

   ```
   source 'https://rubygems.org'
   gem 'gem_you_need'
   gem 'another_gem'
   ```
3. Make sure gems are installed: run `bundle install` in your project root
4. In any file that needs gems, let Bundler load them:

   ```
   require 'rubygems'
   require 'bundler/setup'
   ```

The additional benefit of this is that it also gives you dependency management and let's you properly manage gem versions across environments.

Much more details are in the [Bundler documentation](http://bundler.io/docs.html).